# MFC program has runtime error R6025 on certain Windows 7 32 bit computers only and fixes after installing Visual Studio on it

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc, redistributable

I have a MFC application compiled with Visual Studio 2010.
On a certain computer (32 bit), it had "Runtime error: R6025 pure virtual function call" error message and sometimes a silent close (with no crash).

After convincing the customer to install Visual Studio 2010, the error disappeared automatically. But I don't know why.
The Visual C++ 2010 redistributables (x86) were installed before installing Visual Studio on that PC.

Why installing Visual Studio 2010 on it fixed it even though the redistributables were installed? Maybe the redistributables were corrupted? (If this is possible) Or Visual Studio install other files that can affect?

I need to explain the customer what fixed the error, but I'm not sure.
Is there any safe way to force the application to use the MFC files that I want to avoid these kind of difficult-to-reproduce bugs?

By the way, there was no call to pure virtual function, so I think that there might be some relation to the distributables or some other files.

Comment: R6025 is the runtime error thatb occurs when you call a pure virtual function. Does the error message occur at startup or upon a specific action ?

Comment: *"I need to explain the customer what fixed the error, but I'm not sure."* - Of course not, you modified the only system where the bug **can** be reproduced. You just blew your final chance to diagnose the issue.

Comment: In my experience, that "call to pure virtual" error sometimes happens when you've built against the wrong version of the Windows SDK by setting the [`WINVER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa383745) defines to a higher level of OS than the one you run on. That doesn't explain why the problem was fixed though but make sure the redistributables you installed were for the same Service Pack of VS2010 as you used for the build.

Comment: MichaelWalz: The error message occurred when there was a call of a lambda function. 
IInspectable: You're completely right. I have learnt the lesson. :( However, I would like to know your opinion about what can be the reason of "changing the system".
@RogerRowland: Your comment is the answer. I could reproduce the bug on another computer (R6025).
There was a dll on the .exe folder that were not from Service Pack 1, and the program was built for SP1, so, when that lambda got called, there was that run-time error. 
I want to mark this as answer but I don't know how. Thank you!

Comment: @manujcm ok, thanks - I've converted my comment to an answer, so you can accept and/or upvote if you feel inclined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, that "call to pure virtual" error sometimes happens when you've built against the wrong version of the Windows SDK by setting the [WINVER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa383745) defines to a higher level of OS than the one you run on.

That doesn't explain why the problem was fixed though so also make sure the redistributables you installed were for the same Service Pack of VS2010 as you used for the build.